# laravel mongodb does not save

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

The [documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) doesn't go into much detail about saving data to mongodb.

I've installed a fresh install of laravel and set the up the mongo connections as in the docs, installed mongodb itself.

Created a model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Notifications extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'notifications';

    public static function foo()
    {
        return 'test returning from model';
    }

}
```

And create a simple route to test

```
Route::get('notifiction' , function(){

    $notifiction = new Notifications();

    $arr = array('name' => 'John Doe');

    $notifiction->save($arr);
});
```

But when I run localhost/mongo/public/notifiction I get **Whoops, looks like something went wrong**. I'm not sure what else needs doing to save information to mongodb through laravel?

Comment: Can you check if there's any error in you app/storage/logs/laravel.log? Also on you development environment you might want to change to debug = true in your app/config/app.php so you see more than just "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: My bad it seems, even though I installed mongo, I didn't install the mongodb php library. Stupid.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you add an answer to your question though. Just in case someone has the same issue and searched this question up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is most likely to do with mass assignment. That is laravel treats every thing as unsafe before saving it to database. Thus we have to whitelist the fields we are trying to save.

The way we do this is in model. Lets say you are trying to save data in `Users` table using `USER model`. First open `app/models/user.php` and add following line:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

}

Above, in fillable we are listing `name` as we want to save name from controller (if you have any additional data fill in the array). Now we can save data from controller.

Eg: `User::create(array('name' => 'John'));` will save name in `Users collection`. Please note the name of collection will be the name of the model unless specified otherwise.

[If this does not solve your problem, enable debug by going to `app/config/app.php` and setting `debug =true`. Find the error and try searching.]

Comment: doesn't make sense to me for mongo, which is free-document

Answer (score 2):

You need not to do like model for SQL.

You try model like this

```
class User extends Moloquent {
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'collection1';
    protected $fillable = ['_id','userName','passwd'];
}
```

You can try this to insert

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('collection1')
    ->insert(array(
             '_id' => 'H12345',
             'userName' => 'Nithil',
             'passwd' => 'qwoeuig'));
```

Using `Moloquent` is more convenient in using multiple DBS. For using `Moloquent`, you may register an alias for the MongoDB model by adding the following to the alias array in `app/config/app.php`:

```
'Moloquent' => 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model',
```

This will allow you to use the registered alias like:

```
class MyModel extends Moloquent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP has mentioned the error was due to

> **`Did not installed the MongoDB PHP Library`**

Apart from that, to do mass assignment in Laravel, the fields should either be `"white listed"` or `"black listed"`

To whitelist the field(s) add

`// name, age, username and email could be mass assigned`
**`protected $fillable = ['name', 'age', 'username', 'email'];`**

To blacklist the field(s) add

`// except _id everything could be mass assigned`
**`protected $guarded = ['_id'];`**

to your model file